# Jquery CheckBox selection - Added Fiddle

Tags: jquery, html

Check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjagana/3vAsx/13/)   (not a working copy but should help understand my problem)

Option to Sort **Alphabetically** or By **Category**

user get 2 views of the same results.

Am trying to achieve the following scenario

By default Alphabetically listed

- user check  A2 and clicks on Category i want A2 to be checked in Category section and viceversa

User is viewing by Category

- user check  A2 and B1 and clicks on Alphabetically i want A2 and B1 to be checked in Alphabetical section and viceversa

how can i acheive this in Jquery with My DOM structure as i don't have any unique name Attribute?

```
$('.sort').click(function () {
//Sort event ..check Fiddle     

});
```

Thanks

Comment: Just a semantic point: you should be using lists and not tables for this content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view DEMO here : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3vAsx/17/)

jQuery:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function(){

    var namevar = $(this).attr('name');
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {

        $(':checkbox[name="'+namevar+'"]').attr('checked','checked');
    } else {

        $(':checkbox[name="'+namevar+'"]').attr('checked',false);
    }
});


$('.sort').click(function () {
if (!$(this).hasClass('activesort')) {   
        $('#visiblity1').toggleClass('hidden');
        $('#visiblity2').toggleClass('hidden');
        $('#alpha').toggleClass('activesort');
        $('#cat').toggleClass('activesort');
}


});
```

Comment: Is it possible without name Attribute ?

Comment: You need to have something which links the both A1 checkboxes, A2 checkboxes and so on. I have used name attribute you can use anything you like. This is the most simplest solution for your usecase, however you are free to increase the degree of complexity as per your needs.

Comment: Should be `.prop('checked', true)` and `.prop('checked', false)`